# File Download URL - Does is it matter for Search Engine Ranking?

Tags: seo

Does is matter if I use this URL for a PDF attached to a posting:

```
www.example.com/slug1/posting/xyz.pdf
```

or

```
www.example.com/downloads/xyz.pdf
```

Comment: There are a few questions on here about URL relevance in SEO with a lot of good suggestions. The same rules apply if it's a content page or a downloadable PDF (as PDFs can also be indexed by Google):

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/what-is-good-uri-design

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/include-full-category-hierarchy-in-url-or-only-the-leaf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Google indexes PDF files then a more descriptive URL *will* help in ranking. However the benefit is likely to be pretty small. (This is partly because PDF files generally do not garner many direct links and thus are rare in search results.)

If possible, I would suggest creating a HTML version of the PDF, with a link to "download as PDF". You should end up with a better ranking for the HTML page.